# Drupal 10: argument value resolver via compiler pass gives type error

Tags: symfony, drupal

I'm picking up a bug with a Drupal site that we're upgrading to Drupal 10:

> TypeError: Drupal\my_module\Controller\ApiController::catchAll():
> Argument #1 ($request) must be of type
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request,
> Drupal\my_module\Entity\Channel given in
> Drupal\my_module\Controller\ApiController->catchAll() (line 50 of
> modules/custom/my_module/src/Controller/ApiController.php).

We... seem to be using a custom service to inject the current Channel into the controller via a compiler pass, which was working fine until we tried upgrading to D10. Now it looks like... every argument passed to the controller is a Channel instance?

Service definition:

```
my_module.argument_resolver.channel_resolver:
    class: Drupal\my_module\Resolver\ChannelResolver
    arguments:
        - '@entity_type.manager'
    autowire: true
    tags:
        - { name: controller.argument_value_resolver, priority: 50 }
```

Service provider:

```
class MyModuleServiceProvider extends ServiceProviderBase
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function register(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new ControllerArgumentValueResolverPass('http_kernel.controller.argument_resolver'));
    }
}
```

Compiler pass:

```
class ControllerArgumentValueResolverPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    use PriorityTaggedServiceTrait;

    private $argumentResolverService;
    private $argumentValueResolverTag;

    public function __construct($argumentResolverService = 'argument_resolver', $argumentValueResolverTag = 'controller.argument_value_resolver')
    {
        $this->argumentResolverService = $argumentResolverService;
        $this->argumentValueResolverTag = $argumentValueResolverTag;
    }

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->hasDefinition($this->argumentResolverService)) {
            return;
        }

        $container
            ->getDefinition($this->argumentResolverService)
            ->replaceArgument(1,
                array_merge(
                    $this->findAndSortTaggedServices($this->argumentValueResolverTag, $container),
                    $container->getDefinition($this->argumentResolverService)->getArgument(1)
                ));
    }
}
```

If it's not already clear, I have... very little idea what this code is doing. But we have a bug where a controller isn't getting the agruments it's expecting, and this code seems to be altering the arguments passed to controllers. Apologies for the vagueness of the question, but does anyone have any suggestions for how to debug this? Or why it might be D10 related?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using a custom service to inject the **'Channel'** entity into your controller arguments via a compiler pass. The transition to Drupal 10 seems to have caused a conflict between the expected argument types for your controller methods and the actual arguments being passed. This is likely due to internal changes in the Symfony or Drupal core that might be affecting the behavior of your compiler pass.

**Debugging Steps**

**Check Drupal 10 and Symfony Documentation:** The issue might be related to changes in Drupal 10 or Symfony, especially how they handle service arguments or controller argument resolvers. [Review the migration documentation for Drupal 10](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/migrate-drupal-module) and Symfony to see if there are any breaking changes.

**Debug the Compiler Pass:** Inside your ControllerArgumentValueResolverPass class, you can add debug statements to print the arguments being passed to controllers. This should help you understand what is actually happening during the compilation process.

```
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    // Add debug statements here
    print_r($container->getDefinition($this->argumentResolverService)->getArgument(1));

    // Existing code...
}
```

**Type-check in the Controller:** Before invoking your controller logic, add a type check to see what type of argument is actually being passed.

```
public function catchAll($request) {
    if (!($request instanceof Request)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid argument type');
    }
    // Rest of the code
}
```

**Examine the Resolver:** Check your ChannelResolver class to ensure it is resolving to the correct type. If it's resolving everything to a Channel entity, it may be the culprit.

**Adjust Priority:** You've set a priority of 50 for your custom resolver. Try changing this priority to ensure it doesn't override other essential resolvers.

```
tags:
    - { name: controller.argument_value_resolver, priority: 10 }  # Changed priority
```

**Addressing the Issue**

Depending on what you find during debugging, you may need to:

Modify your ChannelResolver to be more selective in how it resolves arguments, especially now that you're in Drupal 10.
Update the controller method signature to accept different types of arguments, and use runtime checks to handle them accordingly.
Change the priority or conditions under which your custom argument resolver is applied.

Understanding how Symfony's service container, argument resolvers, and compiler passes work will be crucial for debugging this issue. Given that you are upgrading to Drupal 10, this knowledge will help you navigate not only this issue but others that may arise during the migration.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this response. I don't mean to sound rude or ungrateful, but I'm curious; I get the impression that it was largely generated by AI. Was it?